# Freeze the top row of a worksheet

Tags: excel, powershell

PowerShell code creates Excel.

I am trying to freeze top row:

```psh
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $True
$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Add()

$ws.Activate()
$ws.Select()

$excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Select()
$excel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = $true
```

Instead of freezing top row, it freezes center of rows and center of columns, i.e.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Solution in the duplicate post does not work, i.e.

```psh
$excel.Rows("1:1").Select()
$excel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = $true
```

gives the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Rows'.
At D:\Script\upgrades.ps1:231 char:5
+     $excel.Rows("1:1").Select()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Rows:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: What version of MS Excel are you creating? *Freeze top row* only came along with Excel 2007 I think ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically freeze the top row of an Excel worksheet in Excel 2007 VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232920/how-can-i-programmatically-freeze-the-top-row-of-an-excel-worksheet-in-excel-200)

Comment: see [SO: 3232920 how-can-i-programmatically-freeze-the-top-row-of-an-excel-worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232920/how-can-i-programmatically-freeze-the-top-row-of-an-excel-worksheet-in-excel-200)

Comment: @OurManInBananas I am trying that solution and it's not working ..... Using Excel 2007

Comment: take a look at [http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=19692](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=19692)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To freeze the top row you need to select the *second* row:

```psh
$excel.Rows.Item("2:2").Select()
$excel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = $true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple sheets and need to freeze the top row of each sheet:

```
$colSheets = ($Sheet1, $Sheet2, $Sheet3, $Sheet4, $Sheet5)

foreach ($page in $colSheets){
    $page.Select()
    $page.application.activewindow.splitcolumn = 0
    $page.application.activewindow.splitrow = 1
    $page.application.activewindow.freezepanes = $true
}
#After you are done, re-select first sheet (optional)
$Sheet1.Select()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$excel.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1
$excel.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = $true
```

Comment: You should give some explanation to your answer.