# From VBA in Outlook, how do I freeze panes in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am writing a VBA macro in Outlook that references an Excel workbook and makes changes to that workbook.  I want to freeze panes (not "Split") just below row 1.

Here's the code I tried:

```
With Excel.ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 3
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

...and...

```
Dim excApp As Object
Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With excApp.ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 3
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Both threw run-time error 91 at the line `.SplitColumn = 0`.

I appreciate any help or pointers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With freeze panes, it's actually relative to the cursor position, so this is one of the few places where `.Select` is actually necessary.

This code should do what you seek:

```
Dim excApp As Excel.Application
Set excApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

excApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("2:2").Select
excApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

It presupposes Excel is already open.

-- EDIT --

Per @ChrisB, there is a way to do this without the dreaded `.Select`:

```
With excApp.ActiveWindow
    .SplitRow = 3
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Comment: I actually needed GetObject instead of CreateObject.  Your solution works!

Comment: You actually don't need to use `Select`.  Check out [excel vba freeze pane without select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094445).
`Dim excApp As Excel.Application
Set excApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
With excApp.ActiveWindow
    .SplitRow = 3
    .FreezePanes = True
End With`

Comment: That's great.  I learned something today; thanks.  I've incorporated your feedback into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one. Its a Function which you can also use outside from Excel, e.g. from Access or Outlook:

```
Public Sub FreezeHeader(Sheet As Excel.Worksheet, _
                        Optional Rows As Long = 1, _
                        Optional Columns As Long = 0)
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Sheet.Activate      ' must be the active sheet!
    With Sheet.Parent.Windows(1)
        If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False ' always delete the old freeze

        .SplitColumn = Columns
        .SplitRow = Rows

        If Rows > 0 Or Columns > 0 Then .FreezePanes = True
    End With
End Sub
```

And now use it like this:

```
Dim EXL As Excel.Application
Dim Book As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set EXL = New Excel.Application
Set Book = EXL.Workbooks.Open("YourFilename.xlsx")
Set Sheet = Book.Sheets(1)

FreezeHeader Sheet       ' Freezes first row (the usual case)
FreezeHeader Sheet, 2    ' Freezes first two rows
FreezeHeader Sheet, 0, 1 ' Freezes first column
FreezeHeader Sheet, 0    ' Unfreezes all
```