# Excel Freezing too many rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to freeze the top 4 rows in my Excel worksheet, but it's freezing 20 rows.  I'm using the following VBA code to freeze the rows:

```
Range("1:4").Select
With ActiveWindow
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

This is a screenshot, with added notiation show what I want, and what is actually happening.  I scrolled a bit to show the freeze, and you can see that row 20 jumps to 36.  It looks like there's a vertical freeze line between G and H, but it's not important (that could be the right-margin page break).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True` will freeze from the active cell.  Try `Range("A5").Select` first

Comment: @lebelinoz Like Jeeped's answer, this has set the freeze line right after Row 13.

Comment: It's to do with the location of `ActiveCell`, which may not necessarily appear in a selected range like in the answer given by @Jeeped.  See my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to freeze the top 4 rows, reference the 5th row.

```
Range("5:5").Select
With ActiveWindow
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

See [excel vba freeze pane without select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094445/excel-vba-freeze-pane-without-select/34095034#34095034) and [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020).

Without .Select.

```
With ActiveWindow
    If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 4
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Comment: Using your code, the freeze line is after row 13.  I'll take a look at the links you posted.  Thx

Comment: No merged cells.

Comment: That did it.  Using the `Select` method was the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with the *active* cell, which may not necessarily appear in the selected range.  Try:

```
Range("A5").Activate
With ActiveWindow
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, this may affect where your split occurs

The SplitColumn/SplitRow values represent the last cell above/left of the split in relation to the top-left cell that is visible. So if you happen to have code like this:

```
Application.Goto Worksheets(2).Range("A101"), True
With ActiveWindow
 .SplitColumn = 0
 .SplitRow = 10
 .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

The split will be between rows 110 and 111 instead of 10 and 11.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/48672141/9329538). Please note that manually scrolling just before the .split code runs can also cause this.