# Freeze panes with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to freeze the first 2 rows and first 4  columns using:

```
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 4
    .SplitRow = 2
    End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

However this only seems to work if I am in the sheet I want to freeze. But The Command button is in a different sheet, and I would rather not change it. Is there a way of specifying which sheet I want frozen?
I would also be happy with freezing all sheets the same way if required.

Thanks

Comment: Activate the sheet before running the code?

Comment: hi. u have everywhere ActiveWindow... try to change to the sheet u want...

Comment: Thank you. That works I think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel vba freeze pane without select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094445/excel-vba-freeze-pane-without-select)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this... (See comments for explanation)

```
' Don't update the screen
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As worksheet
' Change this if you aren't using the workbook your code is in
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
' Activate the workbook... otherwise you might not be able to activate the sheet
wb.Activate
' Save the current sheet
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
' The sheet to apply FreezePanes to
wb.Sheets("Your Sheet").Activate
With ActiveWindow
    .FreezePanes = False
    .SplitColumn = 4
    .SplitRow = 2
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
' Move back to original sheet
ws.Activate
' Update the screen again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```