# how to freeze top row in excel using vbscript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I use this script to open csv file and save them in another directory as xls file.

I also want to add one more feature - I want to free the top row so that when I scroll down it remain constant. How can I do that?

```
Dim app, fso, file, fName, wb, dir 

dir = "D:\TA\"

dirsave = "D:\TA\XLS"

Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each file In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file)) = "csv" Then  
    fName = fso.GetBaseName(file)

    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file) 
    app.Application.Visible = True
    app.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    app.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dirsave & "\" & fName & ".xls", 56
    app.ActiveWorkbook.Close 
    app.Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
    app.Application.Quit 

    End if
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232927/1188594)

```
Rows("1:1").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code can't be working for more than 1 file.

App.application is same as app in this case; just use app.

Visible and displayalerts can be done once, before the for loop.

Instead of app.activeworkbook, use the variable wb.

Just before save as, use the two lines [provided by Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511957/1188513); prefix the first line with wb.worksheets(1) and second with "app.".

Consider saving as xlsx instead of xls.

Resetting displayalerts and app.quit should be after for loop.