# VBA - freeze pane on different file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010 to for some automation.

In short, I create a new workbook with this method:

```
With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set NewBook = .Workbooks.Add
    .Visible = True
End With

With NewBook
    Set WS = NewBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
End With
```

And now I would like to create a freeze pane.

I've tried using **select** and **ActiveWindow** as on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232920/how-can-i-programmatically-freeze-the-top-row-of-an-excel-worksheet-in-excel-200):

```
WS.Range("F4").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

Somehow when editing different files, .select method always selects the original file instead of the added book.

I then looked at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094445/excel-vba-freeze-pane-without-select) and tried:

```
NewBook.activate
With ActiveWindow
    If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
    .SplitColumn = 5
    .SplitRow = 4
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

No use, freeze pane is created on the original file.

Nor does the following work:

```
With NewBook
    If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
    .SplitColumn = 5
    .SplitRow = 4
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Not sure if my .activate method is wrong, or ActiveWindow is wrong, or maybe .select is wrong. Lots of thanks anyone could help.

Comment: Also, to create freeze pane, it seems VBA always requires ActiveWindow, is there a way to get around it?

Comment: No. It's a property of the window, not the worksheet. You need to use `NewBook.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True` or `NewBook.Windows(1).FreezePanes = True`

Comment: You're creating a new instance of Excel, so you need to reference that instance explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Rory and Tim, it works as I use

    NewBook.Application‌​.ActiveWindow

Answer (score 0):

It's times like this that I try to debug the code through the selective use of msgbox statements. Trying placing a msgbox statement before you run the newbook.activate or the with loop, and outputting the name of the current workbook or worksheet. That should tell you which workbook Excel sees as currently active.

Also...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx
and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195422.aspx

maybe excel is not recognizing the name of the new workbook that you create. It also looks like each workbook has their own index however in the order in which they're created. Perhaps try referring the workbook by index.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ActiveWindow qualify the first (actually unique) window of the new workbook. There is a prerequisite if the workbook has multiple sheets; you need to activate the desired sheet in the workbook to have the FreezePanes applied to the correct worksheet in the workbook.

```
NewBook.Sheets("DesiredSheet").Activate
With NewBook.Windows(1)
    If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
   .SplitColumn = 0
   .SplitRow = 1
   .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when working from a workbook which was itself created from the main workbook. In my case the solution was to add `ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized` before trying to freeze the panes:

```
NewBook.Activate
NewBook.Sheets("DesiredSheet").Select

ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized

With NewBook.Windows(1)
    If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
   .SplitColumn = 0
   .SplitRow = 1
   .FreezePanes = True
End With
```